# How to query the next 2 posts in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am looking to query the next two posts in Wordpress, however, in relation to the current position.

So, for example, if I am on post #1, posts #2 + #3 are displayed. If I am on post #7, posts #8 + #9 are displayed. If possible, I'd like these to loop too, so if post #9 is the last post, and I'm viewing post #8, I will see posts #9 + #1.

Can anybody help me with this?

```
               <?php
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'project',
                    'orderby' => 'date',
                    'order' => 'DESC',
                    'posts_per_page' => '2'
                );
                $query = new WP_Query( $args );
                ?>
                <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
                    <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

                        <div class="unit one-half">
                            <figure>
                                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
                                      the_post_thumbnail();
                                } ?>
                            </figure>
                            <figcaption>
                                <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                                <h5><?php the_excerpt(); ?></h5>
                                <h6><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a></h6>
                            </figcaption>
                        </div>

                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: I think you'll have to write the query WHERE clause yourself, and it will depend on your current post ID. I don't think there's built-in functionality for this in WordPress, but going straight to the SQL should get you there.

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/174008/31545). You must just modify it to show a link to the first post if you are on the second last post

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;

    $args = array (
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => '2',
        'paged' => $paged,
        );  
    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

    while ($wp_query->have_posts()): $wp_query->the_post();
    get_the_title();
    endwhile;

    global $wp_query;

    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

    echo paginate_links( array(
        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
    ) );
?>
```

Comment: Hi thanks, but something seems to break, I'm just getting a links to pages, not actual posts like before. I have updated my original post with my full code.

Comment: ya..it prints title of post.if you want to display all data of post then write code for that inside `while` loop